# Split Multiple Columns Into Multiple Columns by Delimiter

Tags: sqlite

I would like to split multiple columns into multiple columns by a delimiter. I am using SQLite, but I am open to importing into another DBMS, if necessary.

---

An example table, showing how the table currently is, where “;” is the delimiter:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f1845

---

An example table, showing how I’d like the updated table to look:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d6283f

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, you have to do it the hard way with the [instr()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) and  [substr()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) functions:

```
SELECT before_semicolon,
       substr(rest, 1, pos - 1) AS after_semicolon1,
       substr(rest, pos + 1)    AS after_semicolon2
FROM (SELECT before_semicolon,
             rest,
             instr(rest || ';', ';') AS pos
      FROM (SELECT substr(data1, 1, pos - 1) AS before_semicolon,
                   substr(data1, pos + 1)    AS rest
            FROM (SELECT data1, instr(data1 || ';', ';') AS pos
                  FROM example)));
```

It might be a better idea to create a user-defined function like Postgres's `split_part()`.

Answer (score 1):

You said you are open to other DBMS solutions as well.

This is very easy in Postgres:

```
select id, 
       split_part(data1, ';', 1) as Data1_Before_Semicolon, 
       split_part(data1, ';', 2) as Data1_After_Semicolon1, 
       split_part(data2, ';', 1) as Data2_Before_Semicolon, 
       split_part(data2, ';', 2) as Data2_After_Semicolon1, 
       split_part(data2, ';', 3) as Data2_After_Semicolon2,
       split_part(data3, ';', 1) as Data3_Before_Semicolon, 
       split_part(data3, ';', 2) as Data3_After_Semicolon1, 
       split_part(data3, ';', 3) as Data3_After_Semicolon2,
       split_part(data4, ';', 1) as Data4_Before_Semicolon, 
       split_part(data4, ';', 2) as Data4_After_Semicolon1, 
       split_part(data4, ';', 3) as Data4_After_Semicolon2,
       split_part(data5, ';', 1) as Data5_Before_Semicolon, 
       split_part(data5, ';', 2) as Data5_After_Semicolon1, 
       split_part(data5, ';', 3) as Data5_After_Semicolon2
from example;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/RSNO8845

To update it, use the same expression:

```
update the table
   set Data1_Before_Semicolon = split_part(data1, ';', 1, 
       Data1_After_Semicolon1 = split_part(data1, ';', 2)
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks CL., Kirk Saunders, and a_horse_with_no_name. I think I will try PostgreSQL. But, my aim is to update the table, not select. Could you give a rextester example of split_part with update?

Comment: @Xa1: just use those expressions in an update statement

Comment: Okay, so: "UPDATE example
SET 

Data1_Before_Semicolon = split_part(data1, ';', 1),
Data1_After_Semicolon1 = split_part(data1, ';', 2) ..." ?

What about, "select id,", from your example? Is that necessary?

Comment: @Xa1 no, a `SELECT` is not obviously not "necessary" for an [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it was a basic question.  I have a lot to learn. I do know that a SELECT is not necessary for an UPDATE, in general, but it can be, as in:

“Col = (SELECT Col FROM table2 WHERE ID = table1.ID),”.

So,  I wanted to make sure I correctly adapted your example.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not for `SQLite` so this may not be for what you are looking for and it isn't necessarily the same thing for what you are asking for.

In SQL Server this is a function that returns a single column table for each "element" of a string by a certain delimiter.  I know the results come out in a vertical fashion as opposed to horizontal but maybe it helps.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fSplitVarcharString]
(
 @pVarcharString varchar(8000),
 @pDelimiter   char
)  
RETURNS @varcharArray TABLE ( varcharValue  varchar(50) )

AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE 
 @siIndex     smallint,
 @siStart     smallint,
 @siDelSize    smallint

 SET @siDelSize = LEN(@pDelimiter)
 --loop through source string and add elements to destination table array
 WHILE LEN(@pVarcharString) > 0
 BEGIN
  SET @siIndex = CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pVarcharString)
  IF @siIndex = 0
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @varcharArray VALUES(@pVarcharString)
   BREAK
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @varcharArray VALUES(SUBSTRING(@pVarcharString, 1, @siIndex - 1) )
   SET @siStart = @siIndex + @siDelSize
   SET @pVarcharString = SUBSTRING(@pVarcharString, @siStart , LEN(@pVarcharString) - @siStart + 1)
  END
 END

 RETURN
END



GO
```